# Not able to build caffe in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, caffe

I'm trying to create an android app that can identify the object in the image and gives its name as result. I know caffe-library can be used for this but getting error when i run ./build.py .

command :

```
user_name@sysetm_name:~/caffe-android-lib$ ./build.py /bin/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build.py", line 102, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "./build.py", line 94, in main
setup()
File "./build.py", line 24, in setup
call(['curl', '-O', PROTOBUF_URL])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your Question about building caffe for Android? If yes: Maybe you could edit your question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the clone is recursive to include the dependencies:

> *** caffe-android-lib Dependency:
>   Boost-for-Android
>   protobuf
>   Eigen

E.g.:

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib.git
>   cd caffe-android-lib
>   ./build.py $(NDK_PATH)

Or have you tried to install the dependencies (especially protobuf) from source?

Given the dependencies are correctly installed, then you will have a successful caffe-android build:

E.g.:

> https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/6b5e37444b77326ae7b3
>   ...updated 10980 targets...
>   Done!
>   ...
>   [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libcaffe_jni.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcaffe_jni.so